# For each getting all picture boxes

Tags: vb.net

Building a space invaders game framework and having some issues getting each bullet that's on screen.

The bullet is defined/created using the below :

```
Dim Bullet As PictureBox

Bullet = New PictureBox() 

Controls.Add(Bullet)

For Each Bullet As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf Bullet Is PictureBox Then
        If Bullet.Visible = True Then
            BulletTimer.Enabled = True
            Bullet.Top = Bullet.Top - 10
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The problem I've got is that this gets every picture box on screen, including the player and enemies and sends the whole lot flying upwards rather than just the bullets.

Comment: You said you are familiar with C#. You could just write the code in C# and use one of the online converters to get the VB.Net equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Tag property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) present in every control. Set the Tag property of the PictureBox to something that identify your PictureBox as a bullet. For example you can set it to the string "BULLET".
Then your loop checks if the PictureBox has the Tag set and if the Tag property has the value "BULLET"

```
Dim Bullet As PictureBox
Bullet = New PictureBox() 
Bullet.Tag = "BULLET"
Controls.Add(Bullet)
```

....

```
For Each Bullet As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)
   If Bullet.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso Bullet.Tag.ToString = "BULLET" Then
       If Bullet.Visible = True Then
            BulletTimer.Enabled = True
            Bullet.Top = Bullet.Top - 10
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Notice that you can simplify your loop using the OfType(T) extension to retrieve only PictureBox from the controls collection. This remove the need to check if the control is a PictureBox.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks very much Steve!Had not realised I could use Tags like that